# How to fix 1and1/ionos spf record not getting authenticated

Tags: email, spf, ionos

I used ionos/1and1 for my company website and I send e-mails using gmail. The e-mails are hosted by ionos/1and1.
Whenever I send an e-mail to a gmail account I get the following message:
"Be careful with this message
Gmail could not verify that it actually came from domainname.com Avoid clicking links, downloading attachments, or replying with personal information."

I have created a spf recond with a txt in my domain by I guess it could be wrong this is what I'm using

v=spf1 include:_spf.perfora.net include:_spf.kundenserver.de ~all

if that one is not correct will this one work?

v=spf1 include:_spf.perfora.net include:_spf.kundenserver.de include:_spf.google.com ~all

Thank you for the help

Comment: It would help to see the headers of a message received in gmail as it will show exactly what checks are failing. We don’t have enough info here to tell if your suggestions can be effective.

Comment: Is the SPF Mail From a subdomain or the organizational domain that you're using for Header From Domain? I agree that headers would be helpful. Replace privite info with generic things like "example.com"

Answer (score 0):

Add a record

> TXT   @   "google-site-verification=blabla0123456789"

to the zone file of your domain.

You can get the value for blabla0123456789 from

- https://support.google.com/a/answer/183895
- https://search.google.com/search-console/welcome
- https://postmaster.google.com/managedomains

By the way, if you omit any spf record in your zone file ionos will automatically create an appropriate record for sending emails to gmail addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Please add a TXT record with the following details:

```
Type: TXT
Host: @
Value: v=spf1 include:_spf-us.ionos.com include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

Please make sure to use the provided information to create the TXT record.